# Loading spinner not removed after Cordova update

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

My Ionic app was working absolutely fine until I got a message to upgrade Cordova from 6.0.0 to 6.1.0 after running cordova prepare to compile in xcode.

I then received a message to update to cordova-ios@4.0.0 or higher, which I also did.

This is when the trouble started. My app lost resources and I had to start updating plugins too. Did some searching and removed the platform and re-added.

Latest problem, which I can't seem to google is there is now a spinner that won't go away, and won't let me interact with the app. See screenshot below. I've remove all reference to $ionicLoading, even though the loader does not look like this.

Please, any help on where I can start debugging this would be greatly appreciated!

[Mysterious loader that won't remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM7RW.png)

Comment: Can you try to update to cordova-ios@4.1.0 and cordova-plugin-splashscreen (in case you are using it) to master? `cordova plugin rm splashscreen && cordova plugin add http://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen`  `cordova platform rm ios && cordova platform add ios@latest`

Answer (score 1):

Ended up being a problem with Ionic Keyboard. Steps to get it fixed for me was to:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
cordova plugin rm ionic-plugin-keyboard
cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

Removed this code from js:

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
```

Then ran `cordova prepare`